# PHP Warning: ldap_search()

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap-query

I'm trying to implement a github project called ADReset at https://github.com/mprahl/ADReset/

I fixed a few issues that i've found, but i'm having problems trying to setup the Administrative Security Groups. Looking at the apache error logs, I see the following:

```
[Mon Oct 01 04:32:25.705508 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 13411] [client XXXXXX:50840] 
PHP Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in 
/var/www/adreset/resources/classes/AD.php on line 93, 
referer: http://XXXXXX/settings/systemsettings.php
```

Looking at line 93, it part of a function in a class. The function is as follows:

```
public function search($query) {
        if (isset($query)) {
            if ($result = ldap_search($this->ad_connection, 
                $this->connectionSettings['baseDN'], $query)) {
                $data = ldap_get_entries($this->ad_connection, $result);
                return $data;
            }

            else {
                return array();
            }
        }
```

Trying to break down the source of the problem, I added a few error logging and the function is now:

```
        public function search($query) {
        if (isset($query)) {
            error_log(print_r($query,true));
            error_log(print_r("AD Connection Stuffs " . ldap_error($this->ad_connection),true));
            error_log(print_r($this->connectionSettings['baseDN'],true));
            $result = ldap_search($this->ad_connection, $this->connectionSettings['baseDN'], $query);
            if ($result) {
                $data = ldap_get_entries($this->ad_connection, $result);
                return $data;
            }

            else {
                return array();
            }
        }
```

When I run the script via the ui, I see the following errors:

```
[Sun Oct 14 22:41:33.128492 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 3236] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59470] (&(objectClass=group)(sAMAccountName=test)), referer: http://XXXX.XXXX.com/settings/systemsettings.php
[Sun Oct 14 22:41:33.128590 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 3236] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59470] AD COnnection Stuffs Success, referer: http://XXXX.XXXX.com/settings/systemsettings.php
[Sun Oct 14 22:41:33.128608 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 3236] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59470] DC=XXXX,DC=com, referer: http://XXXX.XXXX.com/settings/systemsettings.php
[Sun Oct 14 22:41:33.128990 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 3236] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59470] PHP Warning:  ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in /var/www/adreset/resources/classes/AD.php on line 97, referer: http://XXXX.XXXX.com/settings/systemsettings.php
[Sun Oct 14 22:41:33.129114 2018] [php7:notice] [pid 3236] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:59470] , referer: http://XXXX.XXXX.com/settings/systemsettings.php
```

So, I've broken it down. The $this->ad_connection is returning a result of "Success", the Base DN is returning the correct base DN for the AD server i'm using and even the query is correct. To double check the query worked, I used the Softerra LDAP Browser and did a search. I'm completely lost as to why this function is failing. Any help/direction would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php), `$this->ad_connection` should be the object that's returned from `ldap_connect()`. Is that true in your case?

Comment: That should just be the connection to the ldap server. In the link you sent, that would be the ldap_connect. it's just saved in another function within the same class